# Is it possible to type a thin and hair space without entering the Unicode?

Tags: unicode, special-characters

Is it possible to type a hair space (u200a) and a thin space (u2009) in Ubuntu without entering the Unicode code? Something with the Compose key?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it! Keyboard preferences > Layouts > Options... > Using space key to input non-breakable space character > Non-breakable space at third level, *thin non-breakable space at fourth level*.

(The fourth level is called the same way as the third plus Shift. To set the 3rd level switch, go to Keyboard preferences > Layouts > Options... > Key to chose 3rd level.)

**Update 2022:**
Apologies to all people asking questions in the comments: I have not used Ubuntu GUI for years now, so frankly don't even understand my own answer here :/ I also don't have any hardware on which I could try it. But generally speaking:

- Keyboard levels modify what you get when you press a key: just pressing a key is the 1st level, shift+key is the second level and so on.
- To type a third-level character, press the 3rd level modifier and the key of interest.

Comment: The hair space still to be found, but I probably want too much in the everyday typography.

Comment: What do levels mean?

Comment: So how do you enter them ? How do you type a 3rd level character ?

Comment: I wanted hair space because that is what is supposed to go before and after an em dash.

Comment: Apparently, the answer does not clear. Could you please explain more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

The key bindings for the compose key are configured in the file [`/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libX11/tree/nls/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.pre). There are no bindings for thin and hair spaces there.

You can define your own bindings by creating a file called `.XCompose` in your home directory.

The [kragen/xcompose](https://github.com/kragen/XCompose) repository contains an example compose file that contains keybindings for some common characters that the default config is missing. This is what it defines for thin/hair spaces:

```
<Multi_key> <backslash> <comma>     : " "   U2009       # THIN SPACE
<Multi_key> <space> <n>                 : " "   U202f # NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
<Multi_key> <space> <bar>               : " "   U200A           # HAIR SPACE
```

(`<bar>` refers to `|`, so Shift + `\` on a US keyboard.)